# SQL query for this case?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

There is a Employee table having employee_id and employee_name
I want to insert "james" to this table.
If Employee table already has one "james" record i want his employee_id to be returned
if the table has more than one "james" records (duplicates) do nothing and skip 
if there is no "james", i want to insert "james" and the new employee_id to be returned

Guys how do i write a query for this.

UPDATE: A answer for another of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242749/looping-in-trigger)  solved the issue. Thanks all for your guidance,

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a stored procedure to do this.  Are you familiar with them?  Alternatively, you could query the database multiple times from your server.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Actually the whole thing comes in a stored procedure..i could do some "if"s in it. but i guess there could be a single sql statement to do the duplicate check.

Comment: I would just go ahead with the ifs.  I cannot come up with a single query that behaves the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) statement is what you are looking for.

Comment: maybe, but how?  Why not provide an answer that deals with the question?

Comment: merge is a good option - but the OP has some specific requirements that force the issue to a procedure. once in the procedure, the merge doesn't really buy much vs some more traditional looking if then else type logic.

Answer (score 0):

If it is allowed to use @@Rowcount function:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeId int

SELECT TOP 2 @EmployeeId = employee_id 
FROM @Employee
WHERE employee_name = 'james'

IF @@Rowcount > 1
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Many matching rows found'
    RETURN;
END

IF @EmployeeId IS NULL
    -- INSERT ...
ELSE
    -- RETURN @EmployeeId
```

Comment: Ivan, did you mean to have "IS NOT NULL" in the test?  If the value is not null then the select statement found some data, correct?